# Call javascript function from .innerHTML href

Tags: javascript, href, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am altering a P element on a page by calling it's id with a javascript function and I am trying to call another javascript function called closeWindow from the HREF of a .innerHTML like below.

```
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "<p>You may close this window <a href="javascript:closeWindow();">here</a></p>"
```

However the javascript:closeWindow is not getting called or I should say is not even being read at all and the function fails.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotes are negating one another, as you can see in the code view. Use single quotes or escape your double quotes:

```
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "<p>You may close this window <a href='javascript:closeWindow();'>here</a></p>"
```

Comment: Oh dear I am silly school boy error! Many thanks... will accept the answer when it lets me :-)

Answer (score 0):

how about giving the javascript function some variables like this?

```
var myvar=123;
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "<p>You may close this window <a href='javascript:closeWindow("+myvar+",sometext);'>here</a></p>";
```

the myvar works, but i can't get sometext to work.

this did not work:

```
var mytxt='sometext'; 
var myvar=123;
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "<p>You may close this window <a href='javascript:closeWindow("+myvar+","+mytxt+");'>here</a></p>";
```

Please some help, i get the error reference error: sometext is not defined. It thinks sometext is a variable. Putting sometext in double quotes is resulting to an empty field after the comma and a syntax error.

Found the answer:

```
var mytxt='sometext'; 
    var myvar=123;
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "<p>You may close this window <a href='javascript:closeWindow("+myvar+",\""+mytxt+"\");'>here</a></p>";
```